# Video and Audio automatically starts downloading in html5

Tags: javascript, html, css, aframe

I am new to web programming. I have a question. why do the audio and videos from the background start downloading automatically(download dialog pops up from IDM) when my index.html page opens? I am using Aframe's videosphere in the background.

```
 <video id="video2" loop="true" autoplay src="/vid/waterfall.mp4"></video>

 <a-videosphere id="video-360" src="#video2"></a-videosphere>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This May Help You. **preload='none'** prevent pre download

```
<video preload='none'
       id="video2"
       loop="true"
       autoplay src="/vid/waterfall.mp4"> 

</video>
<a-videosphere 
    id="video-360" src="#video2">
```

For Audio

```
<audio preload="none">
   <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
   Audio Type
</audio>
```